# XAML collapse all child elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF Xaml application. The app has various stackpanels (that behave like icons) that I need to change the Visibility based on certain criteria.

Question:
How can I collapse all child elements (stackpanels)?
I am collapsing each one by one in the backend in vb.net. But much rather find a cool way to do it all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can have two options

1. you can achieve it through style(This will not work if your following MVVM, that is if your binding)
2. Create coustom control

With Style:

Write the style as below with the target type which is used to display the image

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
     <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Height="26" Width="200" Name="text1"/>
        <TextBox Height="26" Width="200" Name="text2"/>
        <Button Height="26" Width="200" Click="Button_Click_2" />
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

TextBox by default will be collapsed you can make it visible based on the search in the backend code

Custom control:

This will be just a wrapper for what ever control your using to display the icon but with only one change is that the default visibility will be collapsed. Then you can make it visible which ever you want

Override hide the already existing Visibility the property with the default value collapsed

Comment: ok, not examply what i had in mind, but I think i can pick up from here. your idea would collapse all textboxes? i'll try to add some key on the element i want to hide, and let xaml handle the hidding. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Bind them using an `IValueConverter` implementation like `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

If that isn't good enough, you will have to do them one by one. Maybe write a custom behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the visibility to parent instead of setting it to each control

For example

```
   <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="pane1">
            <Button Height="30" Width="200" Content="one" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="panel2">
            <Button Height="30" Width="200" Content="two" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

In you back end write the logic to set the visibility for stackpanel instead of each control

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pane1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        panel2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        panel2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        pane1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

If your following mvvm then bind to the visibility property of the stack panel like below

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding CanShowPanel1}">
            <Button Height="30" Width="200" Content="one" Click="Button_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding CanShowPanel2}">
            <Button Height="30" Width="200" Content="two" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: that won't really work. If i hide the WrapPanel, the icons inside will automatically hide. But I want to keep the WrapPanel visible so i can later chose whats icons to show and what to hide. with binding its a show all or show none deal. am I wrong?

Comment: could you please explain your requirement with an example then it would be easy to understand what your actually trying to do

Comment: Ok. I have a WrapPanel that has a bunch of Icons. I am creating a Universal Search field that will show only the icons related to a users query. To do this, I must first hide all the icons, and later show the ones necesary. I am working on hiding all icons in one shot, so as to reduce the amount of code i need to write.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to use `IValueConverter` with parameter.

```
  <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding TheQuery,Converter={StaticResource QueryConverter,ConverterParameter="MyFirstStackPanelVisible"}}">
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding TheQuery,Converter={StaticResource QueryConverter,ConverterParameter="MySecondStackPanelVisible"}}">
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>


public class QueryConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch((string)parameter)
        {
          case "MyFirstStackPanelVisible"
          bool result =CheckQueryCriteriaForFirstStackPanel();
          return Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Collapsed;

          case "MySecondStackPanelVisible"
          bool result =CheckQueryCriteriaForSecondStackPanel();
          return Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Of course you shouldn't make CheckQueryCriteriaFor... function for every case.
This approach guarantee logic to be in one place.